# Create custom Xcode project template?

Tags: templates, xcode6

I want to make a custom project template for in  Xcode.
So that when I start Xcode I can choose from an template I made.
There are a couple of tutorials out there, but most of them are very old (2009-2010) and do not apply anymore (folder structure is different).

Question is like the title, how do I make them?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try of [generator-swift-framework](https://github.com/cybertk/generator-swift-framework), it's used to create a Xcode framework project from a Template Project, and the template can be modified easily according to its [Contribution Guide](https://github.com/cybertk/generator-swift-framework/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).